# Provide methods in Dagger 2

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have problem, i don't know why but my variable don't inject and equals null. 
I provide method like this:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideSource(context: Context): DatabaseSource = DatabaseSource(context, Models.DEFAULT, DB_NAME, DB_VERSION)

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideStoreDB(databaseSource: DatabaseSource): KotlinReactiveEntityStore<Store> = KotlinReactiveEntityStore(KotlinEntityDataStore(databaseSource.configuration))

@Provides
@Singleton
@NotNull
fun provideStores() : Database<Store> = PersistentDatabase(Store::class)
```

And class for model Store:

it is heir from  class "persistable".

```
@Entity
data class Store(val id: Long = 0, val name: String = "", val description: String = "", val date: String = "") : DisplayableItem, Persistable
```

Class for works with DB

```
@Singleton
class PersistentDatabase <T: Any> (val type: KClass<T>) : Database <T> {
    @Inject
    internal lateinit var store: KotlinReactiveEntityStore<T>

    override fun addResult(item: T): Completable = store.insert(item).toCompletable()

    override fun addListResult(item: List<T>): Completable = store.insert(item).toCompletable()

    override fun deleteResult(item: T): Completable = store.delete(item)

    override fun getAllResults(): Single<List<T>> = (store select type).get().observable().toList()

    override fun removeAllResults(): Completable = store.delete(type).get().single().toCompletable()
}
```

In my repository layer i use it like this:

```
@Inject
lateinit var database: Database<DetectedLanguageText>

fun getHistory(): Single<List<DetectedLanguageText>> {
    return database.getAllResults()
            .map { it.sortedByDescending { it.date } }
            .transitSuccessToEmitter(historyEmitter)
}
```

But when i am in function **getAllResults** the variable

```
    @Inject
    internal lateinit var store: KotlinReactiveEntityStore<T>
```

Doesn't inject and equals **null**. Why it doesn't work for me?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see where you inject KotlinReactiveEntityStore in PersistentDatabase. You just create an instance in the provides method, but no injection is done.

Comment: here:  (dog)Inject
    internal lateinit var store: KotlinReactiveEntityStore<T>

Comment: Yes, you marked field as injectable, but you create an instance manually, don't you? So it is up to you to set this field. Dagger will inject field if it creates an instance.

Comment: If you annotate fields with `@Inject` you have to call `component.inject(myObject)` to inject its fields. You did not include any code that hints on you doing so.

Comment: @Guliash no, how can i do it? I thought fun **provideStoreDB** should call automatically when i defenition variable **store** as Inject

Comment: @David Medenjak can you give an example? I thought fun provideStoreDB from DI should call automatically

Comment: @Loxpozizni, why don't you add KotlinReactiveEntityStore as a parameter to constructor? The in you module add argument for provides method, and it should be fun.